# Android Application with phonegap build data not getting on phone

Tags: android, json, cordova

I created a jquerymobile application and built an android package with phonegap build. In this application data is getting from asmx web service methods using jSON. I've installed this package on Android emulator and working fine there. But when I installed this on phone, data from web service is not getting.

Please help me

Comment: Is you android manifest setup properly to allow connections to the internet? Is the hostname/IP address of your web server accessible on the network that your device is on? Are you getting an error or a timeout?